# CocosSharp Accelerometer Axes

Tags: android, xamarin, accelerometer, cocossharp

Ok so i have to create a game for a competiton but i encountered the following problem: I have to get the x ,y ,z Axes of a Acceleromter.**I use xamarin and i create a CocosSharp game**.i manage to get them in MainActivity but i have to get them in GameLayer.Cs. Here i have to use **CCEventAcceleration** and **CCAccelerometer** but it doesn't seems to work.Until now i tryed to get them this way

```
CCEventAccelerate Acl;
CCLabel label;
label = new CCLabel("Score: 0", "Arial", 20, CCLabelFormat.SystemFont);
label.PositionX = 50;
label.PositionY = 880;
label.AnchorPoint = CCPoint.AnchorUpperLeft;
AddChild(label);
```

Then i tryed

```
try
   {
      label.text = Acl.Acceleration.X.ToString();
   }
catch(Exception ex)
{
label.text = ex.ToString();
}
```

Comment: define "doesn't work".  Do you get a compile error?  A crash?  A runtime exception?

Comment: it just say the value is null

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to activate the accelerometer, and register an eventlistener, see example below. Checkout the CocosSharp test project for more details:
https://github.com/mono/CocosSharp/blob/master/tests/tests/classes/tests/AccelerometerTest/AccelerometerTest.cs

```
GameView.Accelerometer.Enabled = true;
var accelListener = new CCEventListenerAccelerometer();
accelListener.OnAccelerate = DidAccelerate;
AddEventListener(accelListener); 

public void DidAccelerate(CCEventAccelerate accelEvent)
{
   label.text = accelEvent.Acceleration.X.ToString();
}
```